# Can't add column to existing table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Trying to add a column to an existing table using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD exp_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER paidthru;
```

**Getting this error:**

> ALTER TABLE users ADD exp_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER paidthru;
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'exp_date'

Answer (score 2):

Try below [Because DATE column doesn't have the default value as "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"]

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `exp_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `paidthru`;
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `exp_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `paidthru`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a DATE column but giving it a DATETIME default which is incompatible.

Use `DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE` instead or change your field to `DATETIME`

Comment: Tried this

ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `exp_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE AFTER `paidthru`;

Still doesn't work. Error is the following:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE AFTER `paidthru`' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

`CURRENT_DATE` is not a valid default, unless you use the new [expression default syntax in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults-explicit):

```
mysql> create table users (id serial primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> alter table users add exp_date date not null default current_date;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_date' at line 1
```

Whoops! Try again, with extra parentheses:

```
mysql> alter table users add exp_date date not null default (current_date);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table users\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: users
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `exp_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT (curdate()),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Looks like it accepted it, but it replaced `CURRENT_DATE` with `CURDATE()`. These are the same.